# React Native Zoom Video sdk real time call with SIP

Tags: react-native, sip, zoom-sdk

I have implemented the zoom video sdk in react native app.When a user start a session then other can join using session name and other info.
But it is not real time.I want to send video call invite from one client to other using SIP.
My question is How  I can call using SIP end point in this case.
How the flow will work?
Are the packages like [sip.js](https://sipjs.com/) or react-native-jssip will be helpfull for this case.
If they are help full then I need the a SIP registration on zoom ?
My case is I have zoom video sdk and I need to call single SIP endpoint and pass some information through x headers.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom Developer Advocate here.

There are two ways to invite a SIP device into a Video SDK session, the first being a client side SDK function call, and the second being a REST API call.

**Client side SDK function call:**

Use the [Video SDK `ZoomVideoSdkCRCHelper` class](https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/custom/reactnative/classes/native_ZoomVideoSdkCRCHelper.ZoomVideoSdkCRCHelper.html) to invite a SIP device.

```js
callCRCDevice(address, protocol)
```

Upon successful call, the SIP device will join the Video SDK session.

**REST API call:**

Use the [Video SDK Use in-session events controls REST API](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/apis/#operation/inSessionEventsControl) to invite a SIP device.

`PATCH https://api.zoom.us/v2/videosdk/sessions/{sessionId}/events`

Headers:

```json
{
   "Authorization": "Bearer {VIDEO_SDK_REST_API_JWT}"
}
```

Body:

```json
{
    "method": "user.invite.room_system_callout",
    "params": {
        "call_type": "sip",
        "device_ip": "device@example.com",
        "sip_headers": {
           "from_display_name": "",
           "to_display_name": "",
           "from_uri": "",
           "additional_headers": {
              "key": "",
              "value": ""
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon successful call, the SIP device will join the Video SDK session.

For questions specific to the Zoom Developer Platform, feel free to ask on the [Zoom devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/).